# Histc - Unexpected results: values classfied in wrong bins

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am getting some unexpected results from Matlab's histc function. I am entering the following

```
x = [0.19 0.06 0.26 0.32 0.35 0.09 0.05 0.21 0.48 0.21 0.23 0.12 0.22 0.16 0.35 0.13 0.34 0.07 0.16 0.45]; %My data

edges = [0.05:0.10:.55];
n=histc(x,edges);
```

Now when I execute the code, I find that n has values

```
>> n
n =
     6     7     5     1     1     0
```

However, based on the Matlab help file I expect (and want):

> Bin [0.05,0.15] = 6
>
> Bin [0.15,0.25] = 7
>
> Bin [0.25,0.35] = 3
>
> Bin [0.35,0.45] = 2
>
> Bin [0.45,0.55] = 2

Am I missing something? Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this result...

Answer (score 2):

It's a floating point issue.

For example:

- Your vector `x` has the value `0.35`.
- Your vector `edge` also has the value `0.35`, calculated by `0.05 + (3 * 0.1)`

But look what happens on Matlab console:

```
>> 0.35

ans =

    0.3500

>> 0.05 + (3 * 0.1)

ans =

    0.3500

>> 0.05 + (3 * 0.1) == 0.35

ans =

     0

>> 0.05 + (3 * 0.1) > 0.35

ans =

     1
```

Matlab thinks `0.05 + (3 * 0.1)` is bigger than `0.35`, and puts it on the "wrong" bin.

If you assign the `edge` array manually, you get the desired result:

```
>> edges = [0.05 0.15 0.25 0.35 0.45 0.55];
>> n = histc(sort(x),edges)

n =

     6     7     3     2     2     0
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael! I suspected this was a precision issue but couldn't seem to figure out a suitable workaround.

Your suggestion does the trick!

Any suggested workaround for larger data sets and intervals to avoid manually entering the edges all the time?

Comment: @mpm166 use `linspace`, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Rafael Monteiro's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927247/2605073) gave you the reason for your problem, to resolve it, use [**`linspace`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html):

```
edges = [0.05:0.10:.55];
X = edges == 0.35

edges =   0.0500    0.1500    0.2500    0.3500    0.4500    0.5500
X =  0     0     0     0     0     0
```

does not define the right bin edge, but:

```
edges = linspace(0.05,0.55,6);   %// 6 = (0.55-0.05)/0.1+1
X = edges == 0.35

edges =   0.0500    0.1500    0.2500    0.3500    0.4500    0.5500
X =  0     0     0     1     0     0
```

does.

---

But why does `linspace` work and the colon operator not? As the documenation actually says:

> The `linspace` function generates linearly spaced vectors. It is similar
>   to the colon operator `:`, but gives direct control over the number of
>   points.

But a closer look into the function shows, that the spaces-vector is generated with integers (`0:n1`), therefore no floating point issues, and **afterwards** scaled to the desired boundaries.

```
n1 = n-1
c = (d2 - d1).*(n1-1) % opposite signs may cause overflow
if isinf(c)
    y = d1 + (d2/n1).*(0:n1) - (d1/n1).*(0:n1)
else
    y = d1 + (0:n1).*(d2 - d1)/n1
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @thewaywewalk ! Very informative post.